# Find loop temination condition variable

Tags: llvm

I want to find the variable which is used to check for termination of the loop,
For example,in the loop below i should get "%n":

```
for.body8:                                        ; preds = %for.body8.preheader,for.body8 
%i.116 = phi i32 [ %inc12, %for.body8 ], [ 0, %for.body8.preheader ]
%inc12 = add nsw i32 %i.116, 1
.....
%6 = load i32* %n, align 4, !tbaa !0
% cmp7 = icmp slt i32 %inc12, %6
br i1 %cmp7, label %for.body8, label %for.end13.loopexit
```

Is there any direct method to get this value?.
One way I can do is by,Iterating instruction and checking for icmp instruction.But I dont think its a proper method.
Please suggest me a method.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way to do this for general loops, it is possible to find this out in some cases. In LLVM there is a pass called '-indvars: Canonicalize Induction Variables' which is described as

> This transformation analyzes and transforms the induction variables
>   (and computations derived from them) into simpler forms suitable for
>   subsequent analysis and transformation.
>
> This transformation makes the following changes to each loop with an
>   identifiable induction variable:
>
> 1. All loops are transformed to have a single canonical induction variable which starts at zero and steps by one.
> 2. The canonical induction variable is guaranteed to be the first PHI node in the loop header block.
> 3. Any pointer arithmetic recurrences are raised to use array subscripts.
>
> If the trip count of a loop is computable, this pass also makes the
>   following changes:
>
> 1. The exit condition for the loop is canonicalized to compare the induction value against the exit value. This turns loops like:
>
>    ```
>    for (i = 7; i*i < 1000; ++i)
>    ```
>
>    into
>
>    ```
>    for (i = 0; i != 25; ++i)
>    ```
> 2. Any use outside of the loop of an expression derived from the indvar is changed to compute the derived value outside of the loop,
>      eliminating the dependence on the exit value of the induction
>      variable. If the only purpose of the loop is to compute the exit value
>      of some derived expression, this transformation will make the loop
>      dead.
>
> This transformation should be followed by strength reduction after all
>   of the desired loop transformations have been performed. Additionally,
>   on targets where it is profitable, the loop could be transformed to
>   count down to zero (the "do loop" optimization).

and sounds like it does just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no general solution to this.  Your question is an instance of the Halting Problem, proven to have no general solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

If you're able to cut the problem space down to something extremely simple, using a subset of operations that are not turing complete (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing-complete), you may be able to come up with a solution.  However there is no general solution.